# Totally ordered $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I know that every $\sigma$-algebra is **partially ordered** with respect to the inclusion operator $\subset$.

However, it seems as though every $\sigma$-algebra should be **totally ordered** with respect to $\subset$ since every set in the $\sigma$-algebra can be compared with respect to $\subset$.

Why is not true that every $\sigma$-algebra is totally ordered with respect to $\subset$? Or is it true?

Comment: I think the informal phrase "can be compared" may be tripping you up - it may not mean what you think it does.  I would suggest you go back and reread the **formal** definition of the phrase *totally ordered*, and I suspect that will clear up your difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it the case that every set in the $\sigma$-algebra can be compared via inclusion? The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, for example, and for any $X$ with $\vert X\vert>1$, this isn't true, since there are distinct elements $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $\{x_1\}$ neither contains nor is contained by $\{x_2\}$.

Comment: Good answer, I am new to this so I appreciate the understanding. One question: is it then proper to say a $\sigma$-algebra is totally ordered with respect to $\subseteq$?

Comment: You can use the same reasoning. Is $\{x_1\}\subseteq\{x_2\}$ or $\{x_2\}\subseteq\{x_1\}$? A tip: when you have a question like this, try drawing a picture. You can get pretty far with basic notions in measure theory by thinking about areas of regions of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

It's false – *very* false – that every set in a $\sigma$-algebra can be compared with $\subset$. The simplest possible example is the $\sigma$-algebra
$$2^X=\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},X\}$$
on the set $X=\{a,b\}$. Then the sets $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are ***non-comparable*** with $\subset$.

The same kind of example occurs with almost any $\sigma$-algebra on a set with more than one element, e.g., the sets $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ are non-comparable with $\subset$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.